# Bash script: "[[: not found"

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ -d ~/viwiki ]]; then
 cd ~/viwiki
else
 mkdir ~/viwiki
 cd ~/viwiki
fi
if ! [[ -d ./log ]]; then
 mkdir log
 mkdir log/log
 mkdir "log/wget"
elif ! [[ -d ./log/log ]]; then
 mkdir log/log
elif ! [[ -d "./log/wget" ]]; then
 mkdir "log/wget"
fi
```

When running, it has errors:

```
tuankiet65@UbuntuPC:~$ sh viwik/test2.sh
viwik/test2.sh: 2: viwik/test2.sh: [[: not found
viwik/test2.sh: 8: viwik/test2.sh: [[: not found
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Maybe the Bash version is too old?

Comment: I don't think so because I am running Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: `[[` is *ancient*, added bash-2.02, released April 1998.

Comment: not even using bash; using sh. run scripts using `./{script}` (after `chmod u+x`), not `sh {script}`

Comment: Old question, I know, but the entire code above could be replaced by the following *mkdir* command: `mkdir -p ~/viwiki/log/{log,wget}`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm guessing that if you run

```
readlink -f $(which sh)
```

you will not get Bash as return value, but Dash. You have the correct preamble, but that only matters if you run the script as `./test2.sh` after making it executable.

Right now you force-run the script via the `sh` interpreter, which probably is Dash, and the `[[]]` construct is a Bash specific one.

That's "why?". If you just replace the double brackets with single ones (and change `#!/bin/bash` to `#!/bin/sh`, since your script is now only using POSIX functions anyway) it should run as intended.

---

Demonstration on Debian, with `test.sh` with contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ "string" == "string" ]]; then
    echo This is Bash
fi
```

this happens:

```
$ readlink -f $(which sh)
/bin/dash
$ sh test.sh 
test.sh: 2: test.sh: [[: not found
$ bash test.sh 
This is Bash
$ chmod 755 test.sh
$ ./test.sh
This is Bash
```

Comment: Thanks :) It fix my problem. I will learn more thing from this :)

Comment: @HồTuấnKiệt: [The Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh) is a good resource on differences between Dash and Bash, with rationale on why the change was made.